# Work around for google app engine image serving webp to unsupported clients?

Tags: google-app-engine, webp

I want to call attention to this issue which is almost a month old and hasn't been acknowledged:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9940

I'm wondering if there's any plans to fix or known workarounds - e.g to force the images to be served in jpg format always via some url modification.

### Full issue description below

We've had some complaints that in Firefox and Safari images aren't showing up. These images have urls that were returned from the get_serving_url(blob_key, ... function listed here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions

For example, this image:

http://lh6.ggpht.com/b8DBpggeo8eZ7TMlJiUJFnMUuBXIkDe_5NZaEtpjfNh9_1BMjxReNBIyU9WMhhb96LDuzndsvdqBaiDiIGIJ=s470-c

Was not rendering in Safari - upon closer inspection using the developer console, I could see it was being served with content-type 'webp', even though Safari isn't saying it accepts image/webp in the request 'accepts' header. Attaching a screenshot of the request / response headers of an image served as webp to safari.

Unfortunately the issue is intermittent - the same image when loaded later may be served as a jpg.

Is it possible the image serving infrastructure is improperly sending back webp images even when the accepts header isn't present? Or perhaps there's some caching server along the way that isn't taking the accepts header into account?

[image]